# Maven integration with Teamcity

Tags: maven, teamcity

I am trying to integrate maven project with teamcity. I almost there but got into one issue. i am using javax mail jar for my project and i have added dependency in POM>xml also.When I am building locally using command prompt it is working fine but when i am trying to buld that on Teamcity I am getting an error stating that "package not found". It means javax mail jar is not being getting included in build. I have tried adding jar from folder by specifying system path then also it is not including. Is there something I am missing in teamcity configuration which is creating this problem ?

Comment: do you have a private repository running? like sonaytape nexus, artifactory or archiva? I would recommend that. Then configure teamcity with a settings.xml (on the root project level) to use that server as mirror for artifacts. Add the private or license restricted jars there so anyone that needs to build the project can access them.

Comment: I got a similar issue with a locally built artifact (not in any public repository). Since TeamCity has means of artifact handling built-in, I assume there must be a better way of handling this than setting up a separate software. 
Anyone?

Comment: Can you add the error to the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments configuring teamCity with a settings.xml where you specify your repository location should do the trick.

Here's a link to TC documentation for Maven builds:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Maven

Comment: Didn't do the trick here - sorry, not a working solution for me. Workaround is installing a separate repository (Artifactory in my case). Still, +1 for providing this link, which may be helpful for others.